# Why won't Groovy honor "OR" instances in my regex?

Tags: regex, groovy

It is well established that "`|`" in a regex is the "`OR`" operator. So when I run this:

```
static void main(String[] args) {
    String permission = "[fizz]:[index]"
    if((permission =~ /\[fizz|buzz]:\[.*]/).matches()) {
        println "We match!"
    } else {
        println "We don't match!"
    }
}
```

**...then why does it print "*We don't match!*"???**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regex `\[fizz|buzz]:\[.*]` matches:

- `\[fizz` - literal `[` followed by `fizz`
- `|` - OR operator....
- `buzz]:\[` - matches literal `buzz]:[`
- `.*` - any character but a newline, as many times as possible, greedy
- `]` - a literal `]`.

I think you need to re-group the alternatives:

```
if((permission =~ /\[(?:fizz|buzz)]:\[[^\]]*]/).matches()) {
```

Here, `\[(?:fizz|buzz)]:\[[^\]]*]` will match a `[`, then either `fizz` or `buzz` without capturing the words, then `]:[`, `[^\]]*` will match 0 or more any characters but a `]` and then `]`.

Check the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/hZ7jF0/1). Also checked at [OCP Regex Visualizer](http://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/java-visual-regex-tester/):

[image]

Comment: I was reminded not to post answers as comments today. Posting.